# How to find the items that are repeated only once in the list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

Let's say we have a `List<Point> Points` as below, how can I get the `Point` objects that are repeated only once in the list: P(30,10) and P(30,0)

```
var Points = new List<Point>
{
    new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 },
    new Point { X = 10, Y = 20 },
    new Point { X = 30, Y = 10 },
    new Point { X = 30, Y = 0 },
    new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 },
    new Point { X = 10, Y = 20 }
};

public class Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = Points
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.X, p.Y }) // Group points based on (X,Y).
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)     // Take groups with exactly one point.
    .Select(g => g.Single());       // Select the point in each group.
```